# Is it possible to run MQL4 code outside of Metatrader?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I have an indicator that is written in MQL4. I'm looking to pass data to it and run it outside of MT4 and, for example, write it to a file. So that I can process the data in Python. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run MQL4 program outside of MT4. 
One can modify the code of the indicator such way that it writes indicator values to some file using FileWrite library function and feed that file to Python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself a simple API that you can run across http and pull the values off GET the URL string and read the values in python.

https://github.com/sergeylukin/mql4-http